# Find the delta between two differently typed lists

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the delta between two lists of different types for which I have a Comparer without looping through the two lists excluding items from the other.
The method should preferably be re-usable and easy to read.

I thought about some linq Except method, but there is no overload for two types and a comparer.

What I was hoping for (made up code):

```
var fromDatabase = new List<T1>();
var fromUI = new List<T2>();

var comparer = new MyComparer();
var theThing = new TheThing<T1,T2>(fromDatabase, fromUI, comparer)

var newOnes = theThing.Two.Where(o=>o.other == null);
var removedOnes = theThing.One.Where(o=>o.other == null);
```

This would encapsulate my comparison logic and I'm hoping to clean up my code by removing some enumerations.

Answer (score 1):

Map list of `T1` to list of `T2` or vice versa (you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for that). Then simple `Except` will do the job.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<T2, T1>(); // create map on application startup

var fromDatabase = new List<T1>();
var fromUI = new List<T2>();
var entitiesFromUI = Mapper.Map<List<T1>>(fromUI); // convert T2 list to T1 list
var newOnes = entitiesFromUI.Except(fromDatabase);
var removedOnces = fromDatabase.Except(entitiesFromUI);
```

Note: you should implement Equals and GetHashCode for type which you are using with Except, otherwise entities will be compared by reference, which will not give expected results, because mapper creates new instances during mapping.

Comment: Sergey maybe a "simple" example would be much better

Comment: This is impossible if there is no mapping function in either direction available. For example if 1 == "true", 2 == "true", and 2 == "unknown" all hold true for the comparer...

Comment: Or map both `T1` and `T2` to a type that describes the common properties his comparer works on.

Comment: @Alexander sorry, didn't get you. As I understand from question, OP has entities from database and some dtos mapped to ui, which represent same entities (otherwise added and removed makes no sense)

Comment: I think @Alexander has a point if there is some fields on the UI class that is not on the DB class and vice versa and those fields are included in the `Equals` then you need a third type as I suggest.

Comment: @weston well, if those fields are included in Equals, then I believe they should present in mapping configuration :)

Comment: Example: DB could have a field for the database context. A property you can't map to UI as makes no sense for the UI class, but might be compared in DB class's `Equals`.

Comment: This is almost what I'm doing now. The problem with that is that I have to have a 'common ground' object and 'how to compare' is hidden over the mappings and my comparer. This ends up with a solution that is at best equally readable as just foreaching through both collections.

Comment: @BorisCallens I can't understand your problems or solve them without knowing T1 and T2 details (as well as your comparer details). I use same approach a lot with database entities and dtos